# Multiple customers forking off same monorepo

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, pnpm, nx-monorepo

I have 5 (soon to be more) clients. For each of them I am developing 1-2 custom apps. Each of these apps requires a react front-end, and functions backend (cloudflare workers). And the apps for a given client roll up into a "container" app, so the route maps can all be combined into a single react and functions deployment. In addition to the 1-2 custom apps for each client, there is 1 shared/common app (auth), a shared UI library, and ideally identical deployment scripts across each of them.

I think a monorepo could work well for this (keep repo structure and common modules on the main trunk, create forks for each client, push up updates to trunk from common modules, all other clients can pull those updates down, when they're ready to adopt that most recent version). I've tried this structure so far:

```
/apps
  /frontend
  /functions
/libs
  /modules
    /shared
      /auth
        /frontend
        /functions
    /client-app-A
      /frontend
      /functions
    /client-app-B
      /frontend
      /functions
  /shared
    /other-shared-lib
```

/frontend and /functions in app directory import their respective folders from each of the modules in /libs.

The challenge is with nx I have no way of incrementally adopting versions or easily contributing updates to sub-modules or shared libs back to trunk.

Any ideas on how to better go about this? I realize git submodules may be what I need but online reviews say it's lot of foot-guns. And ideally there is some way to keep all these as part of the main core repo...

Happy to provide more context if needed... Many many thanks in advance...

Comment: You are hitting the mono repository issue and why we ended up not using it to maintain multiple applications: versioning. We ended up going back to the good old "one project per application and one project per library" and covered things with tests to guarantee non regression - and thus compatibility. The solution lies in having 100% coverage in libraries.

Comment: Damn... well I appreciate your help. Does feel like a hell of a lot of anti-patterns just to shoe horn stuff into a monorepo.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Mono-repositories work wonder for single tools - like Rollup or Babel. But to maintain multiple applications with their own dedicated life-cycles, mono-repositories are very difficult to work with and - in my opinion - create more issues than they solve. In the course of the last 5 years we moved to a 100% coverage paradigm for everything. In the end it allowed us to remove mono-repos (and dependency locking but that's another topic) and to get back to the simplest form of projects prossible.